# get date of series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
In[1212]: x
Out[1213]: 
Open              22.551850
High              22.692506
Low               21.989226
Close             22.036111
Total_Volume    7192.000000
Name: 2006-02-07 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

How do I get `2006-02-07 00:00:00` from the above variable `x` which is a `pd.Series`?

I tried `x.index`, but it returns:

```
Index([u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Total_Volume'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the variable you are looking for is the name of the Series:

```
x.name
```